# Changing grid header postion to fixed on top of document on scroll causing screen to look flicker

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the following code to change grid header class on scroll,but when my grid contains only 2-3 rows on scroll header looks flicker for more than 3-4 rows this is not happening .

```
$(document).on('scroll',function(){
    var height = $(this).scrollTop();

    if(height  >= 83) {
        $(".form_wrapper").addClass("scroll_adv");
    } else {    
        $(".form_wrapper").removeClass("scroll_adv");   
    }
});
```

Comment: A bit formatting required for the code!

Comment: this code should function normally, so your problem is with the css or html maybe! so please put the full code related to this issue.

Comment: In my case when user scroll the window div position is changing to fixed because height >83 but immediately the same event occurs and height changes to height<83 and div changes to same position that causes screen to look flicker .Is there any way to handle this situation in css or html